# Response.Redirect doesn't work after 2 minutes subroutine

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've bound an asp button to a subroutine that generates an xls file through these steps:

1. Executes some sql queries (successfully)
2. Builds the excel file with the resulting data sets (successfully, 2MB)
3. Redirects the current page to a "DownloadPage.aspx?filename=" with the standard operations to build and download the file

But at this point it doesn't start any download even if the excel file is available in the source folder. The strange thing is that sometimes it works, randomly. 
No exception is throwed but the Thread Abort dued to redirection.

So, I haven't other ideas...Do you?

Thanks

p.s. I've tried to set some IIS parameters to 6 minutes or over.

Comment: Fischermaen is probably correct. For long running procedures like that, you probably want to just start working in a separate thread, and send a response to the user saying they'll get an e-mail when the job is done. alternatively, send a response saying the job is in progress, and an AJAX request to poll for completion.

Comment: Nice idea. So how can I show an async notification on the current page? (assume that user can browse the entire site while thread is working...)

Comment: If you want the user to be able to browse the entire site, and get notified wherever they may be, then you'd probably just want to go with the e-mail solution, but there are heaps of other solutions, all somewhat invasive. You could set a session/cookie stating that the current visitor has an active job, and based on that, start an AJAX request on every page load. You could, on each page request, check if the output file is ready, and print a small notification. When I mentioned AJAX, however, I was thinking something smaller in scale, such as a page with visual feedback saying

Comment: "Generating file, please wait", and a little loader icon, until the job is done, rather than having the entire browser request just hang there for two minutes without response while the file is being processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 minutes is a *very* long time for a web request.  Long enough that most clients will give up, either by means of the browser timing out or the user navigating away.  Why does it take so long to fulfill the request?  Is there a significant bottleneck you can improve?  Running some SQL queries and building an Excel file shouldn't take that long.  It's also considered a very bad idea from the perspective of the server to have a request hold up IO for so long.  If there are many users they can grind the server to a halt by normal use of the site.

If it really is supposed to take so long, you may want to consider an asynchronous approach.  Instead of having the user wait for a redirect, immediately provide some kind of feedback.  Send the user to a page indicating that their request has been received and is being processed.  They can then continue to use the site.  When their data is ready, the site can provide some kind of notification link to let them know.

On the back end, the site can either kick off another thread to do the work.  Or, and this is often better for a web application, you can queue the request in a database and have a Windows Service or scheduled console application poll that database for new requests, process them, and save the output where the web application can look for it.  Then the notification system in the web application would just check for output with each request (or maybe poll it via AJAX or something cool like that) to notify the user that the data is ready.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I have a huge SQL Function that requires that time to process. Maybe the separated thread could be an interesting idea... But, how can I verify that my problem is some kind of timeout?

Answer (score 1):

I think the web browser has run into a time-out requesting your page. So the redirect can not work.